# Css3 slider multiple images

Tags: javascript, css

How to create multi items slider with only HTML, CSS?
I want create slider like http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel or http://flickity.metafizzy.co/

[image]

**Thera many variant for one visible item like jsfiddle link q4d9m/170/ but I want 3 items in viewport.**(amount of items displayed at a time with the widest browser width)

Comment: https://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/XjbXVE

Comment: no no no ..... 3 images we must see and prev and next buttons

Comment: dude, thats example of how it can work via css3 only.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by using simple label/radio input hack.
Just click on labels. With a bit more work you could make it into a fuly usable gallery.

```css
label{
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='radio']{
  display: none;
}

.slider{
  position: relative;
}

.slide{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background: no-repeat 50% 50% / cover;
}

.slide_1{
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300)
}
.slide_2{
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/400)
}
.slide_3{
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/150)
}

input:checked + .slide{
  left: 210px;
}

input:checked + .slide + input + .slide{
  left: 420px;
}
```

```html
<label for="slide_1">label_1</label>
<label for="slide_2">label_2</label>
<label for="slide_3">label_3</label>

<div class="slider">
  <input id="slide_1" type="radio" name="slide-changer" checked/>
  <div class="slide slide_1"></div>
  
  <input id="slide_2" type="radio" name="slide-changer" />
  <div class="slide slide_2"></div>
  
  <input id="slide_3" type="radio" name="slide-changer" />
  <div class="slide slide_3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: amount of items displayed at a time with the widest browser width must = 3 when we have >3 items

Comment: I made a small edit to the code to allow it to display three images at once

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Snapper](https://github.com/filamentgroup/snapper) from [Filament Group](https://github.com/filamentgroup)

> A CSS Snap-Points based carousel (and lightweight polyfill)

Comment: code without jquery

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here there are some links/tutorials:

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-image-slider-with-stylized-thumbnails
http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/

Comment: http://codepen.io/drygiel/pen/rtpnE
http://codepen.io/johnmotyljr/full/cDpEH/

It seems that I cannot directly post codepen links

Answer (score 0):

[Link-1](http://xdesigns.net/2013/08/css-slider/)

[Link-2](http://www.cssscript.com/pure-html-css-responsive-carousel-cari/)

**or you can use a plugin nivo-slider with few lines of jquery code

To add the navigation for a slider you need js/jquery .